# How can I access identifying info for each facet in a Seaborn rel plot (so that I can lookup/apply xlims from table)

Tags: python, seaborn

Using Seaborn rel plot, how can I access identifying information for each facet grid? I am trying to adjust the x-axis limits for each subplot. Below is an example, and I commented where I am stuck.

```
## Make dataframe to work with
mydf = sns.load_dataset("planets")

tempdf = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "method": [
            "Radial Velocity",
            "Imaging",
            "Eclipse Timing Variations",
            "Transit",
            "Astrometry",
            "Transit Timing Variations",
            "Orbital Brightness Modulation",
            "Microlensing",
            "Pulsar Timing",
            "Pulsation Timing Variations",
        ],
        "x1": [1950,1975,2000,1990,1990,2001,1875,2005,1945,1900,],
        "x2": [2075,2020,2015,2015,2030,2100,2020,2020,2200,2000,],
    }
)

mydf = pd.merge(mydf, tempdf, how='outer', on='method')
mydf.head(5)

## Make plots
g = sns.relplot(
    data=mydf,
    x="year",
    y="distance",
    col="method",
    col_wrap=4,
    kind="scatter",
    facet_kws={'sharex': False, 'sharey': False}
)

for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.grid(b=True, which="both")
    ### ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
    ### I want to set these as the (x1,x2) values for each "method"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: use `g.axes_dict`

Comment: I see that now in the [facet grid docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html), thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit convoluted, and there's probably a better way to do it but this code works.

```py
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.grid(b=True, which="both")
    method = ax.title.get_text().split('=')[1][1:]
    xmin = tempdf[tempdf['method']==method]['x1'].values
    xmax = tempdf[tempdf['method']==method]['x2'].values
    ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
```

Comment: I ended up doing `xmin = mydf[myd['method']==panel]['x1'].unique()[0]` to avoid any ambiguity in relating `mydf` to `tempdf` (the latter could be in any order)

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip`:

```
for ax, xmin, xmax in zip(g.axes.flat, tempdf['x1'], tempdf['x2']):
    ax.grid(b=True, which="both")
    ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
```

Output:

[image]